# How to prevent update of v-model input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Normally, when user types some value in input field the value is automatically updated in a model. What I need is to prevent value from being updated automatically for some period of time. In my app I draw a grid on canvas. User types length and width in input fields. I want to trigger drawing a grid when `width` is set by user, not earlier (I use `watch` for that reason). The issue is that when user types width e.g. 57 then it first draws a grid of width=5 and right after that the width=57. It means I finally have 2 grids. The reason is that Vue responds immediately to what user types in input.

I tried to get around it somehow using `v-model.lazy` but it doesn't work. I also tried to use `setTimeout()` but it doesn't seem to work at all. I commented out this chunk of code in my reproducible example:

```
    function draw() {
    for (var j=0; j<rows; j++) {
        for (var i=0; i<cols; i++) {
            tile = new Rectangle({width:size, height:size, borderColor:"#a8a8a8", borderWidth:0.2})
                .centerReg(tiles)
                .loc(size/2 + i*(size), size/2 + j*(size));
        }
    }
    }

    setTimeout(draw, 3000) // here I wait 3 sec after user inputs value in this field
```

Generally speaking - I want the program to wait until user inputs lenght and width and once values are input then draw a grid.

Here is a reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-vuex-drag-and-snap-to-tiles-un6984?file=/src/components/ZimModel.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be solved if whatever function that makes the grid gets triggered with a `@blur` attribute on the input field (which triggers when a user leaves the input field)

Or by adding the `@input` attribute which triggers a function that calls a setTimeOut (every time clears the said timeOut before setting it, to avoid multiple code executions), and if the timeOut finishes before getting cleared by another keystroke, your function gets executed.

Comment: Do I need to use `clearTimeout` function here or `setTimeout` itself automatically clears previous keystroke?

Comment: You need to use clearTimeout, note that for you to be able to clear the timeout outside of its scope, it needs to be a global variable, meaning registering a variable in your data object, assigning its value to the setTimeout function, and then clearing the variable by clearTimeout, therefore `clearTimeout(this.myInputTimer)`.

Comment: Yes, I did like that and it works, thanks!